# What is the "+:" operator called in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am going through a Verilog test case, and I found this statement:

```
assign XYZ = PQR_AR[44*8 +: 64];
```

What is the "+:" operator known as? I tried to find this on google, but I didn't get any relevant answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That syntax is called an **indexed part-select**.  The first term is the bit offset and the second term is the width.  It allows you to specify a variable for the offset, but the width must be constant.

Example from the SystemVerilog 2012 LRM:

```
logic [31: 0] a_vect;
logic [0 :31] b_vect;

logic [63: 0] dword;
integer sel;

a_vect[ 0 +: 8] // == a_vect[ 7 : 0]
a_vect[15 -: 8] // == a_vect[15 : 8]
b_vect[ 0 +: 8] // == b_vect[0 : 7]
b_vect[15 -: 8] // == b_vect[8 :15]

dword[8*sel +: 8] // variable part-select with fixed width
```

Answer (score 3):

Lastly i got the source page for this, this is called as [Indexed Vector part Select ("+:")](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2001-SNUG-presentation_Verilog-2000_standard.pdf).

To explain it a bit more

```
PQR_AR[44*8 +: 64];
```

With Indexed vector part select, which is added in Verilog 2000, you can select a part of bus rather then selecting whole bus.

44*8 part is starting point of part select variable and 64 is the width of part select andis constant.It means that if initially we have initialized

```
input [415:0] PQR;
```

we are selecting a particular part of PQR using

```
PQR_AR[44*8 +: 64];
```

that is PQR_AR[352+:64] or it means that we are taking a part from 352 to 415 out of 0 to 415.

Comment: From dwikle answer derived from LRM, when we initialize a bus like: input [415:0] PQR; Then, PQR_AR[44*8 +: 64] should be PQR_AR[352:288] and not PQR_AR[415:352].
Please correct me if I am going in wrong direction.

Comment: @ABX I agree about the direction, except it should be PQR_AR[352:289] to be a 64 bit wide bus