# Indexed Vector Part select operator +: usage in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am using [Indexed Vector Part Select](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74277/what-is-this-operator-called-as-in-verilog) in a Verilog test case and i am very confused with this.

when we have described

```
input [415:0] PQR_A;
output [63:0] ABC;
```

then is it valid

```
assign PLA=PQR_A[44*8 +: 64]
```

because i think in this way the bits will be from 352 to (352+ 64) i.e. 416, which is not valid

I know this is quite silly to ask that what is [0:7], it means 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 i.e. 8 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexed vector select `w[x +: y]` has width `y`. The equivalent regular select is `w[x : (x+y-1)]` .

Comment: Code has little endian notation, so first answer is right

Answer (score 1):

one line explanation of that  is :

w[x +: y] == w[(x+y-1) : x ]

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this: `w[x +: y] == w[(x+y-1) : x ]`

For example:

`a_vect[ 0 +: 8]  == a_vect[ 7 : 0]`

Comment: Can you elaborate why your answer has the order flipped from the already accepted answer?